# SSRS 2008: Some Multi-Value Paramaters Blank/Unselectable When Creating Subscriptions

Tags: parameters, ssrs-2008, subscriptions, multivalue

I have a report set up with 9 different multi-value parameters.  When I go to create a subscription for the report and specify the values of these parameters, only 4 of them will allow me to click on the drop-down list to expand and select options.  The other 5 show blank textboxes by default (even though there should be multiple values already selected by default), and clicking on them does nothing.

Their properties are all over the place - some are integers while others are text, and some have hard-coded values specified by me while others get their values from datasets.  However I cannot find any consistency between the ones that don't work and the ones that do.

Here's a screencap of the subscription setup page - all of the multi-valued ones showing a blank textbox are un-clickable.

[image: SSRS 2008 Subscriptions]

I'm using Internet Explorer 9 where the all of the web interface features of the reporting system navigator have worked for me thus far.

Just looking for something to help send me in the right direction towards finding the root of the problem here.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution found here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/sqlreportingservices/thread/6E11EC25-E205-469E-8C35-B73B4478BCF0?prof=required

It's a JavaScript error that happens if one of the LABELS of a value of a multi-value parameter is a blank string.  If you have any blank labels, change the labels to be something like "(blank)" and everything should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have Cascading Parameters, e.g. Product Status depends on Product Types?  In that scenario you have to either:

1. set up defaults for every child Parameter, or
2. remove the "Use Default" checkbox on the parent Parameter and choose the required values. This will allow SSRS to generate the pick list for the Child Parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  None of my parameters rely on each other (i.e. the selected value(s) of parameter A do not determine the available values for parameter B, or vice versa).  In regards to your first suggestion, I considered it, but one of my parameters that doesn't work is "Filter by Day of the Week," which doesn't pull from any dataset.  Their available and default values are hard-coded by me. (Sunday, Monday, etc.)  And I've already considered the second suggestion; however removing the checkbox still leaves the select list unusable.